# Visual C++ 2010. How to include header files which reside in another included project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have 1 project. I imported in this project many external VC++ projects. 
I wanna to import in a .c file which resides in one of the included projects a .h (header file) which resides in another included VC++ project.
How can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the properties for the project, add the location of the header files to the

```
C/C++ | General | Additional Include Directories
```

item.

To get the library project linked in, add a reference to it in the:

```
Common Properties | Framework and References
```

item.

I wish that adding the project reference would get the IDE to automatically add the refered-to project directory to the include file path, but it doesn't.

Comment: Man I really wish it could add the include folder as well :/

Answer (score 2):

You should add a path to the other project. It's preferred to use the macros like `$(SolutionDir)` to refer to other projects in the solution.